# How to log on jazz team server?

Tags: rational-team-concert

I've installed jazz team server from `RTC-Web-Installer-win-4.0` using IBM installation manager , then  I start server and try to create new jazz repository connection using RTC visual studio client , using URI of localhost with port 9332 , ID : "ADMIN" , password "ADMIN" then I got this error:

```
CRRTC8521E: Failed to contact the repository 'ADMIN@localhost'
```

Note : I'm using windows 7 .

[From jazz.net](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/109596/cant-log-on-to-jazz-team-server), the call stack:

```
 Apr 14, 2013 11:21:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\jre\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\x64\;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\;.
Apr 14, 2013 11:21:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"]
Apr 14, 2013 11:21:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9443"]
Apr 14, 2013 11:21:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"]
Apr 14, 2013 11:21:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 4724 ms
Apr 14, 2013 11:21:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 14, 2013 11:21:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25
Apr 14, 2013 11:21:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\tomcat\webapps\admin.war
Apr 14, 2013 11:21:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\tomcat\webapps\ccm.war
Apr 14, 2013 11:22:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\tomcat\webapps\clmhelp.war
Apr 14, 2013 11:22:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\tomcat\webapps\converter.war
Apr 14, 2013 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\tomcat\webapps\jts.war
Apr 14, 2013 11:22:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\tomcat\webapps\qm.war
Apr 14, 2013 11:23:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\tomcat\webapps\rm.war
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.perfCounters.layout
Apr 14, 2013 11:23:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Mai\Desktop\RTC4\server\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
Apr 14, 2013 11:23:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"]
Apr 14, 2013 11:23:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9443"]
Apr 14, 2013 11:23:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"]

Apr 14, 2013 11:23:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 116808 ms
```

-I tried to ping on server using the URI /jazz/ or URI/ccm/

but ping request couldn`t find that URI telling me to check name and try again

Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer to complete the installation process from your answer on jazz.net. For setting e-mail configurations, please post a new answer (here and/or on jazz.net)

Comment: It is not clear here. Did you run the setup after installing? You can create the workspace only after finishing the setup.

Answer (score 3):

@ all : many thanks for your help ,

i finally could create new repository from visual studio client with the following solution :

- installing new server and client in administartor mode , using c:/RCLM4-SERVER for server , c:/RCLM4-CLIENT for client , c:/RCLM-SHARED for client shared files.
- after start server configure it according to https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_s_server_installation_setup_wizard.html&scope=null using URI : `https://localhost:9443/jts/setup` , user name and pw are ADMIN , while setup i changed those user name and pw to new ones .
- create new project using previous web client .
- create new repository from vs client using uri : `https://localhost:9443/ccm` , using name localhost ,new ID and PW during server setup ,**here is the clue in using the right port 9443 and right mode ccm and correct name from vs client**.

Comment: Interesting feedback (I have echoed it in my answer below) +1

Answer (score 1):

The error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.perfCounters.layout
```

is covered by work [item 60463](https://jazz.net/jazz03/web/projects/Requirements%20Management#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=60463) (you need a -- free -- jazz account to see it)

> I checked the latest log4.properties that we ship. It has the following entry:

```
# Sometimes Log4j complains, so lets substitute the PatternLayout for right now
log4j.appender.perfCounters.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
```

It isn't described as a blocking error, though, which means your instance probably doesn't work for another reason.

Makes sure the [JTS ADMIN access is enabled](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21314276).

And double-check the [deployment and start of JTS within an Apache (Tomcat) server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/c_deploying_tomcat.html).

---

As [mentioned in jazz.net](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/109596/cant-log-on-to-jazz-team-server?page=1&focusedAnswerId=109604#109604), the right addresses to use are:

- `https://localhost:9443/jts/setup`
  or
- `https://localhost:9443/jts/admin`
  or
- `https://localhost:9443/ccm/admin`

Provided you did an installation as Administrator.

> When you install your RTC server, it will generally consist of two apps, CCM and the JTS (though from the tomcat console output you pasted above, I see you installed all the CLM products, which consists of JTS, CCM, QM, and RM).
>   After installing, you should visit `https://localhost:9443/jts/setup` to setup the JTS, register CCM, and setup CCM. Your login will be `ADMIN/ADMIN`.
>
> After finishing setup, you can then connect your RTC client to your CCM.
>   The URL you will use for your connection is **`https://localhost:9443/ccm`**.
>   Note that you may have disabled the `ADMIN` user during setup. If so, you will have to provide a username and password for the user you created during setup.
>
> Your problems above were that you were:
>
> - either **using the wrong port** (`https://localhost:9332/ccm`)
> - or **using the wrong context root** (`https://localhost:9443/jazz`)
> - or you added extra which shouldn't have been there (`https://localhost:9443/ccm/admin`).

---

The OP reports having been able to complete the installation:

> I finally could create new repository from visual studio client with the following solution :
>
> - installing new server and client in **administrator mode**.
> - after start server configure it according to "[Running the setup by using Custom setup in the setup wizard](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_s_server_installation_setup_wizard.html&scope=null)" using URI : **`https://localhost:9443/jts/setup`**, user name and password `ADMIN` (during the setup, I changed those user name and pw to new ones).
> - create new project using previous web client.
> - create new repository from vs client using uri: **`https://localhost:9443/ccm`**, using new ID and PW during server setup.

Comment: i`ve checked JTS ADMIN , unfortunately in teamserver.properties i didn`t find com.ibm.team.repository.ws.allow.admin.access=false to change it to true !!

Comment: @PrettyRose maybe you could add it and see if the issue persists?

Comment: @ VonC : thanks for reply ,i also checked http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_run_rqm64_win_service.html , i already follow it ,

Comment: @ VonC:i added the admin access property but no change , still can`t log on server !!

Comment: @PrettyRose is it still with a `CRRTC8521E` error message? http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.messages.CLMic%2FCRRTC8521E.html

Comment: @PrettyRose `CRRTC8521E` means "The server might not be running, the client might not able to connect to the server because of inadequate permissions, or the user name, password, or both are incorrect", so double-check the Tomcat logs: something must not be right when contacting that server.

Comment: @ VonC : yes same error still exist , ok i`ll check tomact logs

Comment: @ VonC : i checked server logs (ccm and ccm-etl) and all tomact logs but the strange thing is that when try to login to server and that CRRTC8521E appear , nothing change in logs (nothing was sent to server and nothing was transmitted from server ) , server not affected !! , is this means that server URI is wrong ??

Comment: @PrettyRose or that means the server is never contacted, i.e. the address is wrong. What kind of uri are you using?

Comment: @PrettyRose is it possible that the Tomcat isn't configured to llisten to localhost?

Comment: @ VonC : i donn know what do you mean exactly , actually i didn`t change any configurations concerning Tomact

Comment: @ VonC : In Tomact config , tomact users xml : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<tomcat-users> <role rolename="JazzUsers"/> <role rolename="JazzGuests"/> <role rolename="JazzProjectAdmins"/> <role rolename="JazzAdmins"/> <role rolename="manager"/> <role rolename="JazzDWAdmins"/> <user roles="JazzUsers,JazzAdmins,JazzProjectAdmins" password="b521caa6e1db82e5a01c924a419870cb72b81635" username="ADMIN"/> </tomcat-users>

Comment: @ VonC : in Tomact conf server i find this : </Realm> -<Host name="localhost" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="webapps">

Comment: @PrettyRose config looks good, but if no log is changed during the query... something else isn't working properly. Is there any other file that could be modified just after ding a `https:// "localhost:9332/ccm/`?

Comment: @ VonC : i used this for download https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0?p=gettingStarted   , did i forget to download needed things ?

Comment: @PrettyRose I wouldn't know but everything should be there. That what the section "Plan and prepare" is for.

Comment: @PrettyRose did the comment on jazz.net help? https://jazz.net/forum/questions/109596/cant-log-on-to-jazz-team-server?page=1&focusedAnswerId=109604#109604

Comment: @ VonC : yes i did and i`ve just seen the reply there

Comment: @PrettyRose I have included that jazz.net answer in my answer above, for more visibility.

Comment: @ VonC : i`ve just tried mentioned addresses in jazz.net , pinging server gives same result while creating new jazz repository connection results in new error : CRRTC8500E

Comment: Exception message:
CRJAZ2384E Cannot connect to the repository at URL "https://localhost:9443/ccm/admin", see the nested exception for more details.

Comment: Inner exception:
Exception type:
com.ibm.team.repository.TeamRepositoryException
Exception message:
invalid UUID [<!DOCTYPE html>]
Status code:
0
Remote exception type:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Request URI:
http://localhost:1033/service/com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.rest.IFilesystemRestClient/Login

Comment: @PrettyRose At this point, it would be better to retry a full installation from scratch, following and double-checking the installation procedure, in order to see if you missed anything.

Comment: @ VonC: doing installation as ADMIN , i`m not sure i did so i think i`ll remove it and install again

Comment: @ VonC : as mentioned in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/65892/cant-connect-to-a-jazz-team-server ,  we have to configure server before accessing it 
via a client. For instructions, see:

https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/topic/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_s_server_installation_setup_wizard.html
and i miss this point so i`ll care by in next installation.

Comment: @PrettyRose ok, let me know how it goes and I will update the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two problems, the first is that you've got an incorrect URL, the second is that you haven't finished all the setup as some of the final setup must be done using the admin account on the web client.

> using URI of localhost with port 9332 , ID : "ADMIN" , password
>   "ADMIN" then I got this error

That's in contrast to the information provided by the RTC server:

```
Apr 14, 2013 11:23:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"]
Apr 14, 2013 11:23:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9443"]
Apr 14, 2013 11:23:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"]
```

According to that information the ports Rational Team Concert is listening on are 9080, 9443, and 9009. The default URL for admin access should be `https://localhost:9443/jts/admin`. You'll want to visit that URL via a web browser first because there's some final setup you'll need to do, such as creating a new project.

After creating a new project, you can invite yourself to the project with a non-admin account. You'll get an invite which will allow the Visual Studio RTC client to connect to the RTC repository much more easily.

Comment: @ Pridkett : thanks alot for reply , i already tried the web browser using https://localhost:9443/jts/setup and i followed steps mentioned in https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_s_server_installation_setup_wizard.html&scope=null , but it gave me CRJAZ1579E error when make test connection and accordingly still client log in give me same error!!

Comment: this error CRJAZ1579E appeared when i changed localhost name in uri , while continue on local host just give warning and couldn`t allow me make test connection , but however client couldn`t log to server after doing so too.

Comment: @ pridkett : after ending final setup and created new project , i tried to invite myself but seems i shall make E-mail configuration settings first and there it asked me about SMTP server name (is it new server to install ??)

Answer (score 0):

All, I had the same issue after installing Jazz locally. Logging in the first time I used Admin>Admin. Had I read more carefully, I would have seen that the default login when hitting the https://localhost:port/jts/setup are UPPERCASE ADMIN>ADMIN.

The instructions here https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_s_server_installation_setup_wizard.html&scope=null do say that. Read carefully!

Answer (score -1):

@ VonC : according to email configuration settings , here are the question and answer as mentioned in jazz:

> when setting e-mail configurations using
>   https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_s_server_installation_setup_wizard.html&scope=null
>   to enable mail invitation , i needed to set some values ,are these
>   values correct ?   SMTP Server name (smtp.localhost.com)
>
> SMTP Username (same as jazz server ID )
>
> email from address (name@localhost.com)
>
> as when i use these values then test connection it gave me : Exception
>   reading response;nested exceptionis : java.net.socketTimeoutException:
>   Read time out , any ideas ?!

the solution is in using correct server name (127.0.0.1 or localhost) or add the mentioned server name in host file in c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc.
and it works with me now using localhost or 127.0.0.1 but also it shows that test succeeded on email settings page , i found error 505:invalid and this fixed by disabling email scan feature in norton but in both cases of norton ..i rxed the mail in spam .
notice : i changed the from address to my email and didn`t use any user name or pw as my smtp server needs no authentication to work (it was misunderstand to use username and pw of jazz server)